# How to free memory allocated with jShortArray/jByteArray from JNI, Java and C++

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, jnienv

I am trying to free the memory of t_data which is assigned as dummy variable. (The code is below). Now as soon as I free t_data the program throws a heap corruption error but instead if I copy all the stuff from body to a new memory for t_data, everything works fine. The delete code is called somewhere down the line in another class method (not shown here), it just uses t_Data pointer to delete the memory.

```
jshortArray val = (jshortArray)(m_pJVMInstance->m_pEnv->CallStaticObjectMethod(m_imageJ_cls, method_id, arr, (jint)t, (jint)c));
jsize len = m_pJVMInstance->m_pEnv->GetArrayLength(val);
jshort* body = m_pJVMInstance->m_pEnv->GetShortArrayElements(val, 0);       
unsigned short int* dummy = reinterpret_cast<unsigned short int*>(body);
//t_data = dummy; //NOTE: Once you free t_data later exception is thrown.
t_data = new unsigned short int[len];
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    unsigned short int test = *(body + i);
    *((unsigned short int*)t_data + i) = test;
}
```

I am trying to figure out a way where I dont have to run the for loop to copy the body data to t_data and still be able to free the memory. (The for loop takes too much time for big images.)

Comment: Check the documentation to find out who is responsible for deleting `body`. I'm no JNI guru, but it's very possible that the garbage collector manages it for you. Don't `delete` stuff unless you allocated it or the API documentation says you are responsible for deleting it. Prefer not to allocate it in the first place.

Comment: A quick look into the subject says the array's memory is locked into place until you call `ReleaseShortArrayElements`. Again, look up the appropriate documentation page for details.

Comment: God willing someone who actually knows this stuff can drop by and give this a real answer. If not, see if you can throw a bone to other programmers who run into this problem by turning the results of your work and research into an answer.

Comment: I would instead focus on figuring out a way to get the needed functionality without using `t_data` in the first place. (This would require more context than is in the question.)

Comment: Yes, definitely don't call `free` or `delete` on the pointer returned by `GetShortArrayElements`, because you don't know what `GetShortArrayElements` did internally. It might not have allocated any memory at all. Some implementations just pin the Java array to avoid having it moved by the GC, and then returns a pointer to the actual Java array contents. Just call `ReleaseShortArrayElements` when you're done with the pointer.

Comment: @Michael or Remaldeep, you should post that as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Michael said was correct and that indeed solved the problem. Referring to his comment:

> Yes, definitely don't call free or delete on the pointer returned by GetShortArrayElements, because you don't know what GetShortArrayElements did internally. It might not have allocated any memory at all. Some implementations just pin the Java array to avoid having it moved by the GC, and then returns a pointer to the actual Java array contents. Just call ReleaseShortArrayElements when you're done with the pointer. – Michael